# Is there an Elixir function which is equivalent to Python's itertools.accumulate?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I would like to use a function that takes an enumerable and a function and does the same thing as Python's itertools.accumulate. For example,

```
iex> accumulate([1,3,7], &Kernel.+)
[1, 4, 11]
```

For an explanation, it's equal to `[1, 1+2, 1+4+7]`. Does such a function exist in Elixir's standard library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Enum.scan/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#scan/2) does the same thing.

```rb
Enum.scan([1, 3, 7], &+/2)
#⇒ [1, 4, 11]
```